# Add foreign key to request Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request, show, foreign-key-relationship

what i am trying to achieve is :
User create a Delivery by a title input,
When the user send the request i want to get the users_id to add it to delivery table as a foreign key.
Here is the deliveries table

```
     public function up()
{
    Schema::create('deliveries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('deliveries', function ($table) {


        $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

here is the DeliveryController

```
    <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   use App\Http\Requests;

   use App\User;

   class DeliveryController extends Controller
   {
       public function index()
       {
           return view('delivery.index');
       }

       public function create()
       {
           return view('delivery.create');
       }

       public function store(Request $request)
       {
          $this->validate($request, [
          'title' => 'required'
          ]);

          $input = $request->all();

          $input['users_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

          Delivery::create($input);

          return redirect()->back();
       }

   }
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of researches i found That my Controller Missing This Line :

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in Two ways

Way 1)  Get the user_id and insert it manually like :

```
$user_id = User::select('id')->where('id',$request->user()->id)->get(); 
Or use this bit to get the current loggedin user_id : $request->user()->id
```

Way 2) Use Eloquent Models

Create a relationship in User Model such as : hasMany, ManyToMany or OneToOne depending on the one that works for you.

```
public function deliveries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
```

And simply call this `$user->deliveries()` to insert `user_id` automatically.

I guess the problem with your code is here :

```
$input = $request->all();

$input['users_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

Delivery::create($input);
```

Can you try this :

```
$delivery= new Delivery;//here Delivery is the Model name
$delivery->title         = Input::get('title');
$delivery->user_id       = $request->user()->id;
$delivery->save();
```